# Redirect on Apache not working

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, node.js

I'm trying to create a subdomain for my node app in my domain with Apache in a Ubuntu machine.

this is my app.conf

ServerName mysubdomain.domain.com.br

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app/

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location "/">
            ProxyPreserveHost On
            ProxyPass http://mypublicip:3000/
            ProxyPassReverse http://mypublicip:3000/
    </Location>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bot_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bot_access.log combined
```

But when I access mysubdomain.domain.com.br I get a list of all files from /var/www/html instead of the hosted app. And when I access myip:3000 I get the app running.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Start by adding the output of `apachectl -S` to your post. I also have two suggestions. Don't use `ProxyPass` inside a `<Location>` block, just use the 2 argument version of `ProxyPass`. Also you do not need a `<Proxy *>` block, these are (almost) exclusively used to configure forward proxies, not reverse.